# How to grep only matched files with count?

Tags: bash, grep

I have many text files and I want to list all files that contain `foo`.

`grep -rc` will display both matched and unmatched files, but i only want to see matched files. So I came up with this ugly pipeline:

```
grep -rc "foo" | grep -v ":0$"
```

The pipeline drops auto coloring.

Can I get the same result without a pipeline?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Did not give the correct result. In my pipeline, `:0` is generated by the first `grep`, not part of the input itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GNU grep doesn't provide such a feature. But you can tell grep to always color the output, then filter out lines ending in `:<some ANSI escape codes>0` like this:

```
grep --color=always -rc 'foo' | grep -v $':\x1B\[m\x1B\[K0$'
```

<sup>(`$'...'` syntax is a bash extension though.)</sup>

Below is a screenshot of the result on my terminal.

[image]

---

See [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Nice uncoloring. I made recoloring as well: `grep -rc "foo" | grep -v ":0$" | grep -P --color=always ".*(?=:)"`

Comment: imo this has the least amount of "magic": `grep --color=always -rc "foo" | grep -v "[^0-9]0$"`.